# HTACCESS setting HTTPS as default, so redirect to / will skip the first HTTP redirect

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a simple htaccess redirect rule:

```
RewriteRule ^directory$     /   [R=301,L]
```

Which currently does the following redirect structure:
 `https://mywebsite.com/directory` ->  `http://mywebsite.com`->  `https://mywebsite.com`
(notice the HTTPS vs HTTP).

The 2nd redirect is due to rule set to handle HTTP->HTTPS redirection:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !mywebsite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mywebsite.com/$1 [L,R=301]  

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpg|png|gif|bmp)$ [nc]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But I would like to avoid that double step. How do I set HTTPS as the default for htaccess?

Comment: There is no such thing as “the default for htaccess”. Show us your full rule set.

Comment: @CBroe added the HTTPS redirect. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @CBroe when I specify in htaccess a redirect to "/" how is he supposed to know if that's https or http ?

Comment: Anything you do not explicitly specify or overwrite is based on the original request. So if all you do is rewrite to `/`, then that will mean a redirect to `http://example.com/` if the original request was made via HTTP, or `https://example.com/`, if it was HTTPS ...

Answer (score 3):

> How do I set HTTPS as the default for htaccess?

Just use `https://` URL in redirect:

```
RewriteRule ^directory/?$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=301,L,NE,NC]
```

Comment: Yes `HTTP_HOST` variable represents domain name in current request URL.

Comment: So basically, for htaccess the default is always http, and if I want that differently I need to specify in each url redirect rule?

Comment: Default (as in your first redirect rule in question) is to redirect to current scheme. So if `http://` stays at `http://` and `https://` stays at `https://`

Comment: But as I showed, the `https://mywebsite.com/directory` is being redirected to `http://mywebsite.com` and not keeping the current schema, just to get redirected again later

Comment: Your rule won't make `https -> http`. It could be either bad browser cache or some other code/config somewhere

Comment: Is there a htaccess config for default scheme? Maybe in the header? document root?

Comment: There can be another .htaccess in `directory/` or some rule `httpd/vhost` config or else some code/plugin.

Comment: So the virtual hosts file of Apache can set that? I'll look inside.